# library implementation for reference counting classes

Tags: c++, boost, std, reference-counting

I have a class like so:

```
Texture
{
    int ID
public:
    Texture(std::string name){ ID = make_texture(name); }
    ~Texture(){ delete_texture(ID); }
};
```

but the problem is that when I move the class, the destructor is called so the ID is now invalid.

my current implementation would be something like:

```
Texture
{
    static std::unordered_map<int> m;
    int ID
public:
    Texture(std::string name){
        ID = make_texture(name);
        m[ID]++;
    }
    Texture(Texture& obj){ *this = obj; }
    Texture &operator=(Texture& obj){
        ID = obj.ID;
        m[ID]++;
    }
    ~Texture(){
        if (!--m[ID])
            delete_texture(ID);
    }
};
//was coded in stack overflow so syntax may be a bit off
```

but what would really be nice is a class I could inherit from like:

```
Texture : public ref_count<int>
{
    int ID
public:
    Texture(std::string name){ ID = make_texture(name); }
    key(){return ID;} // inherited from ref_count
    on_delete(){ delete_texture(ID); } // inherited from ref_count
};
```

so my question is: does a convenient class like this exist in the standard / boost library? Or what is the best way to achieve this without implementing my own reference counting.

Comment: a `shared_ptr<Texture>` will keep the texture alive as long as someone holds a shared_ptr referencing it. thats the closest I can think of in the standard library

Comment: @kmdreko yeah i thought about it but the wrapper is so ugly since you have to use `std::make_shared` and i really want to preserve the ease of construction of the class

Comment: Then wrap the `ID`. Have `Texture` hold a shared_ptr to int, with a custom deleter.

Comment: @StoryTeller could you show me how it would work as an answer?

Comment: note that you do not reuse the texture of same name, like`Texture a("name"), b("name")` this may not be what you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To expand on my comment. You need `Texture` objects to be shared references to the same `ID`, so it's `ID` that needs to be wrapped in some reference counting type for `Texture` to hold. That's exactly a use case for `std::shared_ptr`. All you need is a [custom deleter](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/shared_ptr) that would `delete_texture` as part of freeing the managed integer.

```
class Texture
{
    std::shared_ptr<int> ID;
public:
    Texture(std::string name) :
      ID{ new int(make_texture(name)),
          [](int* id_ptr) {
            delete_texture(*id_ptr);
            delete id_ptr;
          }
        }
    {}
};
```

And that's it. The copy/move/dtor of `Texture` can now be implicitly generated by the compiler, since it relies on the correct behavior of `std::shared_ptr`.